# Symbolic ticks with subscript - ListPlot

Tags: plotting, ticks, education, subscript

Is it possible to rename ticks with a name like this: "$0.125 \, V_{FS}$"?

In the below code I wrote "$0.125 \, V$", I don't know how can I insert the subscript.

```
ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {0.125, 0.125}, {0.25, 0.25}, {0.375, 0.375}, {0.5, 
   0.5}, {0.625, 0.625}, {0.75, 0.75}, {0.875, 0.875}}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, FrameTicks -> {
   {{{0, "000"}, {0.125, "001"}, {0.25, "010"}, {0.375, "011"}, {0.5, 
      "100"}, {0.625, "101"}, {0.75, "110"}, {0.875, "111"}}, 
    Automatic},
   {{{0.125, "0.125 V"}, {0.25, "0.25 V"}, {0.375, "0.375 V"}, {0.5, 
      "0.5 V"}, {0.625, "0.625 V"}, {0.75, "0.75 V"}, {0.875, 
      "0.875 V"}}, Automatic}
   }, Frame -> True]
```

Thank you for your willingness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {0.125, 0.125}, {0.25, 0.25}, {0.375, 0.375}, {0.5,  0.5},
  {0.625, 0.625}, {0.75, 0.75}, {0.875, 0.875}}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{{0, "000"}, {0.125, "001"}, {0.25, "010"}, {0.375, "011"},
  {0.5, "100"}, {0.625, "101"}, {0.75, "110"}, {0.875,  "111"}}, Automatic},
  {{#, Row[{ToString@#, Subscript[V, FS]}]} & /@ Range[.125, .875, .125], Automatic}},
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: today you are my personal professor!

Comment: @Gennaro, glad i could help.